# for_each to avoid raw loop

Tags: c++, stl

I'm trying to rewrite some of my code using the STL algorithms (C++11) and I got stuck at the "No raw loops" rule.

I have this piece of code in one of my functions:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < cars->size(); i++) {
        if (cars->at(i).getNumber() == nr) {
               throw RepositoryException ("Product with the same number already exists");
        }
    }
```

cars is of type  vector

nr is an int I get as a parameter

This for loop really only does some validity, the whole function does something else so my question is, is there a nice way for replace this loop with some STL algorithms? for_each seems like a try but I can't figure out how to use it since I can't really make another function only for this specific validity.

I saw ways of doing it using a lambda inside the for_each but I'm not sure how to do that either.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to avoid raw loops?

Comment: It's a thing I'm required for a course. After two weeks of working on some code, we have to apply the "No raw loop" rule on everything but at this part, it beats me. http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Cpp-Seasoning

Comment: Perhaps `std::find_if()`? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::for_each(cars->begin(), cars->end(),
  [=](const Car& c) {
    if (c.getNumber() == nr) {
      throw RepositoryException("Product with the same number already exists");
    }
  }
);
```

But really, most of the time `for_each` makes code harder to read than a plain loop.

For this case, I could also press `find_if` into service:

```
if (std::find_if(cars->begin(), cars->end(),
      [=](const Car& c) { return c.getNumber() == nr; })
    != cars->end()) {
  throw RepositoryException("Product with the same number already exists");
}
```

It's not clear that this is any easier to read, either.

Answer (score 5):

If you're compiling with C++11, I recommend `std::any_of`:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
if (std::any_of(std::begin(*cars),std::end(*cars), 
   [&nr](const Car& c){return c.getNumber() == nr;})
{
   throw RepositoryException ("Product with the same number already exists");
}
```

I assumed that `cars` contained objects of type `Car`

Answer (score 2):

You can [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) like this:

```
if (std::find_if(begin(*cars), end(*cars),
       [&](const auto& v) {return v.getNumber() == nr;}) != end(*cars))
  throw RepositoryException ("Product with the same number already exists");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for_each` in this case as follows:

```
std::for_each(cars.begin(), cars.end(),
  [nr](Car& c){
    if(c.getNumber() == nr)
      throw RepositoryException ("Product with the same number already exists");
  });
```

Though IMO C++11's range-based loops are cleaner:

```
for(auto& c : cars) {
  if(c.getNumber() == nr)
    throw RepositoryException ("Product with the same number already exists");
}
```

Comment: Not I'm slightly confused if the c++11's for you've meantioned counts as a raw loop sort of thing or not. Thank you for the alternative

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You did not say which version of C++ you are coding for.</strike>  Other answers gave you solutions for C++11 and later. Here are some pre-C++11 solutions, in case anyone else needs them:

```
struct checkForProductNumber
{
    int nr;
    checkForProductNumber(int n) : nr(n) {}

    void operator()(const Car &c)
    {
        if (c.getNumber() == nr)
            throw RepositoryException ("Product with the same number already exists");
    }
}

void someClass::doSomething()
{
    //...
    std::for_each(cars->begin(), cars->end(), checkForProductNumber(nr));
    //...
}
```

```
struct hasProductNumber
{
    int nr;
    hasProductNumber(int n) : nr(n) {}

    bool operator()(const Car &c)
    {
        return (c.getNumber() == nr);
    }
}

void someClass::doSomething()
{
    //...
    if (std::find_if(cars->begin(), cars->end(), hasProductNumber(nr)) != cars->end())
    {
        throw RepositoryException ("Product with the same number already exists");
    //...
}
```

Comment: All this is happening inside a function which belongs to a class with a certain structure I have to follow. That's why I said I don't really know how making another function would fit in and the for_each with a lambda inside seemed like the most readable "no raw loop" solution I could find. And yes, c++11, my bad. I'll edit and specify for future references. I wish I could choose more answers. Thank you

Comment: @Katie44: Lambdas did not exist prior to C++11. And what I showed can be used inside your existing class functions. But since you are using C++11, you can ignore my answer and use a lambda instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau `what I showed can be used inside your existing class functions` If I recall correctly, pre-C++11 local classes couldn't be used as template parameters. Only names with external linkage could be. So there would have to be *something* outside of existing functions.